# Pythonic way, syntax-sugar or operator for applying a function to self?

Tags: python

Imagine having a long-named or nested collection/dictionary of function objects, if I want to apply decorator to some of them based on certain conditions, I'll have to:

```py
long_long_name[some_key][some_other, key] = my_decorator(long_long_name[some_key][some_other, key])
```

Is there a pythonic way / syntax-sugar to do it ? like plus-equal for addition to self ?

```py
a = a + b # can be written as
a += b

a = b(a)
a ◯= b # something like this ?
```

Comment: The decorator syntax (@decorator) is already syntactic sugar for what you're ending up having to do, but it only applies when `def`-ing the function/method. If you want to apply it later on (conditionally even), you'll have to stick with your original approach AFAIK

Comment: If the functions themselves can be decorated during their definition, you could define some syntax like `long_long_name[some_key][some_other, key] @= my_decorator`, but I don't think I'd consider that beautiful or pythonic.

Comment: you want an `__icall__` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it would be a good idea, but something similar to what you want is possible.

If you can decorate all your callables, you could add such an operation, for example with the `@=` operator, which is usually not defined for functions:

The first step would be to declare the decorator that you have to apply to all of your callables:

```
class decoratable:
    def __init__(self, fn):
        self.fn = fn
    def __matmul__(self, other):
        return decoratable(other(self.fn))
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.fn(*args, **kwargs)
```

If you manage to decorate *all* of your callables with this decorator, then you can use `@` to combine them with other decorators:

```
@decoratable
def add_2(x):
    return x + 2

long_long_name = {"some_key": {("other", "key"): add_2}}
```

Let's define an example decorator that prints when you call the function:

```
def printer(fn):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print(f"Calling {fn.__name__}")
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

Then, finally, this becomes possible:

```
>>> long_long_name["some_key"]["other", "key"](3)
5
>>> long_long_name["some_key"]["other", "key"] @= printer
>>> long_long_name["some_key"]["other", "key"](3)
Calling add_2
5
```

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no built-in syntax-sugar way of doing this as of python 3.8. The built-in assignment operators are

```
=
+=
-=
*=
/=
%=
//=
**=
&=
|=
^=
>>=
<<=
@=
```

as taken from the docs from the `operator` library: https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html.