# Gradient Descent Reassignment in Pytorch

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I was following a series of tutorial on youtube about deep learning, and I encountered a problem which really confuses me.

```
X = torch.tensor([1,2,3,4], dtype = torch.float32)
Y = torch.tensor([2,4,6,8], dtype = torch.float32)

w = torch.tensor(0.0, dtype = torch.float32, requires_grad=True)

def forward(x):
  return w*x;

def loss(y, y_predicted):
  return ((y-y_predicted)**2).mean()

print(f'Prediction before training: f(5) = {forward(5):.3f}')


learning_rate= 0.01
epoch = 20
for i in range(epoch):
  y_pred = forward(X)
  l = loss(Y, y_pred)
  l.backward()
  with torch.no_grad():
    w = w - learning_rate * w.grad
    # (w -= learning_rate * w.grad) # would not cause error in the following line


  w.grad.zero_() #error : 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'zero_'
  if i % 1 ==0:
    print(f'weight : {w}, loss : {l}')
```

I really wonder the difference between "**w = w - learning_rate * w.grad**" and "**w -= learning_rate * w.grad**" cause these two are the same in my expericence. Thanks!

Comment: New *w* has no grad because it is assigned after `l.backward()` and no `requires_grad` because of `torch.no_grad()`. It is not equivalent in `pytorch`, `w[...]= w - learning_rate * w.grad` is. Btw: comments are marked by an `#` in python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out in the comment, the problem is in how Pytorch computes/stores gradients. In fact,

```
w-= learning_rate * w.grad
```

is an in-place operation, which will make w keep its initial properties (the requires_grad=True). Usually in Pytorch, we avoid in-place operations as it may break the computational graph used by Autograd (see [Pytorch Forum Post](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/vae-gan-inplace-operation-error/143895)).

But for you, this:

```
w = w - learning_rate * w.grad
```

is not in-place. Thus, w is assigned to a new copy, and because of the torch.no_grad() statement, this copy won't have a .grad attribute.

Comment: I kind of understand what you mean. `w = w - learning_rate * w.grad` is reassigning, and it is in the scope of `with torch.no_grad()`, so the new w would not have gradient, which causes the following error. However, `w-= learning_rate * w.grad` is a in-place operation, so it is manipulating with the original w, and it has the `gradient = True `. Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

Although [operators are working](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_operators.asp) in [`python`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) with a specific behavior, this is [not always true](https://pythonshowcase.com/question/what-is-the-purpose-of-with-torch-no_grad) for the [`pytorch`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/index.html) framework. For the vanilla [`python`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) interpretation, we could watch that the [subtraction assignment](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/subtraction_assignment.html) of `A -= B` is equivalent for `A = A - B` syntax. Additionally, [python operators](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/#assignment-operators) can be used [every time you want to assign a value to a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37845498/2371987). In fact, we call this [syntactic sugar](https://zsiegel92.github.io/Eitan_S/Lessons/Lesson_6_Lists/Python6.html) in [`python`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html), and it can be used to [simplify your code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58507331/2371987). However, things work differently for the [`pytorch`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/index.html) framework.

In your case, the new *w* is assigned after `l.backward()` being propagated. Hence, it has no `grad` value. Moreover, the *w* assignment has no `requires_grad` because of the `torch.no_grad()` condition.

Now, let's take into account your example:

```py
w = w - learning_rate * w.grad
```

In the [`pytorch`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/index.html) framework, it is equivalent to:

```py
w[...] = w - learning_rate * w.grad
```

Although `w[...] = w - learning_rate * w.grad` and `w -= learning_rate * w.grad` might seem equivalent, they don't follow the same structure. Hence, they promote different behaviors. On the one hand, the `w -= learning_rate * w.grad` expression is considered as an [in-place operation](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/what-is-in-place-operation/16244). Meaning that it changes directly the content of a given tensor (*e.g.*, `w[...]`) without making a copy. On the other hand, the `requires_grad=True` attribute is making *w* keep its initial properties. Therefore, not updating its state.

Comment: This is obviously not correct for `pytorch` tensors as the code runs differently in the example provided. In-place operators can be overloaded independently.